# Input/Output size for various transaction types

Tags: transaction-fees

What are input/output sizes for various transaction types?

I see some numbers like 210 byte for input for p2sh-p2wpkh here ([How do virtual size, stripped size and raw size compare between legacy address formats and native segwit?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/84004/how-do-virtual-size-stripped-size-and-raw-size-compare-between-legacy-address-f#)), but curious to know more detailed breakdown of input/output for each transaction types.

Answer (score 0):

This website (https://www.buybitcoinworldwide.com/fee-calculator/) shows the approx size of transactions according to the address type, number of inputs and number of outputs and the final fee (after you set how much sat/byte you want to pay)

As you play with it you will see that the most important if you are worried about fees is to reduce the number of inputs. The best practice is to consolidate your small inputs in native segwit addresses (bc1...) when fees are low.

This way when you need to transfer bitcoins when the network is congested you will have a smaller transaction size, paying less fees.

Be careful with your **privacy** while doing so.