# Bitcoin Transactions Detailed distinction between TxHeader TxInput TxOuput

Tags: transactions

Related to post [Murch Explanation of Segwit Tx Fee Rate](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/84004/how-do-virtual-size-stripped-size-and-raw-size-compare-between-legacy-address-f) he breaks a TX down into:

- TxHeader
- TxInput
- TxOutput

To calculate the weight and the final virtual size of a transaction (P2PKH,P2WPKH,P2SH-P2WPKH)

My question relates to what is the TxHeader in detail. I haven't heard about this classification in any articles.

Answer (score 1):

When I look at the following Transaction Description [Transactions](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transaction) I see the following distinction so I conclude:

TxHeader:

| Field | Size (in bytes) |
| --- | --- |
| Version no | 4 |
| Flag | 2 (optional only for segwit v0 right now) |
| In-counter | 1 - 9 bytes (varint) |
| Out-counter | 1 - 9 bytes (varint) |
| lock_time | 4 bytes |

TxInput:

| Field | Size (in bytes) |
| --- | --- |
| list of inputs | (in-counter)-many inputs |

TxOutput:

| Field | Size (in bytes) |
| --- | --- |
| list of inputs | (out-counter)-many inputs |

Comment: Can somebody confirm ?

Comment: The header can vary. You are nearly right. Basically it starts with version and inputCount. If the inputCount = 0 then the inputCount is the flag and the inputCout follows. If the initial inputCount is > 0 then its the inputCount and the inputs are following.

Comment: FYFI I coded exactly that data reading: https://github.com/mrqc/bitcoin-blk-file-reader/blob/master/analyze.py

Comment: See the readTransaction(...) function there.

Comment: Ok so what your are essentially decribing is, how the algorithm is implemented,got it, but I think looking at your code when the 5 th byte is 0 then the next byte is the flag (not the already read inputCount) and the 7th Byte is the inputCount. Thanks for the Code Snippet very pratical for understanding

Comment: Yes, but be aware: Inbetween those values the inputs' data is there, so you maybe dont want to include this data in a "header".